# Javascript window.location search for "#" never returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to set up a redirector so that when my AJAX functions change the hash part of the URI, the link is still directly accessible should it be copied and pasted.  My current function is below; however, it always returns false!

```
//If a hash is found, redirect it
var current_uri = String(window.location);

if (current_uri.search('/\#/') != -1) {
        var current_uri_array = current_uri.split('#');
        window.location = current_uri[1];
}
```

How can I change the code to make this work?  Is there a better way of doing this?

Code updated to:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
    window.location = window.location.hash.substring(1);
}
```

Which worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `window.location.hash` directly ;)

Comment: I updated the code to:

//If a hash is found, redirect it
if (window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location.hash.substring(1);
}

And this worked.  Thank you.